# Objective-C NSMutableArray: Organize array of photos by date key

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have an array of dictionaries..looks like this.

```
(
   {name = somename;
    date = NSDate;
    other_params = some other params;
   },
   ...
)
```

How can I then sort the array items by NSDate (oldest to newest or vice versa). Do I just do a basic select-sort algorithm or is there a shorter way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort the array using descriptors or using comparators, whatever you feel more comfortable with. Here is an example of using comparators:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [myArray sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2) {
    return [[obj1 date] compare:[obj2 date]];
}];
```

Comment: Good answer.  However, given that they are dictionaries, which don't have a `date` property per se, you have to use `[obj1 objectForKey:@"date"]` and similarly for `obj2`.

Comment: Or you could just replace id with the object type you are passing

Comment: @aryaxt, the signature of the block is set by the signature of `-sortedArrayUsingComparator:`. Also, using `NSDictionary*` instead of `id` would not help with the use of a fictional `-date` method.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the sort descriptors option:

```
// Adjust the 'ascending' option to invert the sort order.    
NSSortDescriptor *dateSortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES];
// The sort descriptors have to go into an array.
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:dateSortDescriptor];

NSArray *sortedArray = [myArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

You can also sort in place if you're using an `NSMutableArray` and don't need to keep its original order.